# Is "assume a noun" possible, instead of assume that~?

Tags: verbs, clauses

The verb to assume is followed by a clause or to infinitive.
Though dictionaries don't mention it, for me, it seems correct to use this structure: assume + a noun. For example:

> Assume a sudden increase in population, ~

Is such a structure appropriate, or should it be written in the clause?

Comment: "Assume" can certainly be transitive. See here: [link](https://www.lexico.com/definition/assume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a noun is the **direct object** of the verb *assume*, most of the time the connotation of the verb is undertaking some role or task:

> When the owner of the company died, he *assumed* **the powers** of CEO.

But for the meaning of *assume* as "take as true," a noun can serve as direct object:

> I think it's a racism thing when you *assume* **things** about Ed.

This is common in mathematics:

> If we *assume* **the Riemann Hypothesis**, the real part of ρ is always 1/2.

Comment: Assume a fire. How do you escape?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey How? Easy. As long as we're assuming, I assume a working sprinkler system.

Comment: If you assume... (etc).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey *Assume* makes an ash out of "u" and "me"?